# Displaying the numbers in an R correlation matrix diagonally

Tags: r, heatmap, psych

I am generating a correlation matrix using

```
library(psych)
corMat = cor(data)
cor.plot(corMat,numbers=TRUE,colors=TRUE,n=51,main=NULL,labels=NULL)
```

but want to alter it so that the numbers displayed inside the heatmap are displayed diagonally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may have misunderstood but if you just want the text labels rotated, you can do so by changing the source of `cor.plot`, specifically the line `text(rx, ry, round(r * 100))` to  `text(rx, ry, round(r * 100), srt=45)`, giving something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like `cor.plot` can pass any arguments through to the `text` call that plots the numbers. So, you can modify the function but opening the source (`edit(cor.plot)`) and changing the line

```
text(rx, ry, round(r * 100))
```

to

```
text(rx, ry, round(r * 100), srt = 45)
```

or however many degrees you want to rotate the numbers by. Then you can copy that code and define a new function (`my.cor.plot`) with the modified code.

I think that there's less hack-ish ways of doing this, but I've never used them and this will work.

Answer (score 1):

That is a great suggestion and is now implemented in psych version 1.3.10.11 (to be released today to Cran). This is done by adding ... to the text command. Specifically,

text(rx,ry,round(r*100),...)

This has the advantage of making use of the power of the graphic parameters.

As of today you can now specify cor.plot(correlation.matrix, numbers=TRUE,srt=45).

Thanks.

Bill